# Missing characters from input stream from fastcgi request

Tags: c, apache, fastcgi

I'm trying to develop simple RESTful api using FastCGI (and restcgi). When I tried to implement POST method I noticed that the input stream (representing request body) is wrong. I did a little test and looks like when I try to read the stream only every other character is received.

Body sent: `name=john&surname=smith`
Received: `aejh&unm=mt`

I've tried more clients just to make sure it's not the client messing with the data.
My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // FastCGI initialization.
  FCGX_Init();
  FCGX_Request request;
  FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0); 

  while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) >= 0) {
    // FastCGI request setup.
    fcgi_streambuf fisbuf(request.in);
    std::istream is(&fisbuf);
    fcgi_streambuf fosbuf(request.out);
    std::ostream os(&fosbuf);

    std::string str;
    is >> str;
    std::cerr << str;  // this way I can see it in apache error log

    // restcgi code here
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using fast_cgi module with apache (not sure if that makes any difference).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems to be an encoding issue every second char is skipped (16/8 bit)

Comment: but how? if it was interpreting 2B as one char then the char would be something else but it is correct in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding no answer anywhere (not even FastCGI mailing list) I dumped the original fastcgi libraries and tried using fastcgi++ libraries instead. The problem disappeared. There are also other benefits - c++, more features, easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem as well, on an unmodified Debian install.

I found that the problem went away if I supplied a buffer to the `fcgi_streambuf` constructor:

```
const size_t LEN = ... // whatever, it doesn't have to be big.
vector<char> v (LEN);
fcgi_streambuf buf (request.in, &v[0], v.size());
iostream in (&buf);
string s;
getline(in, s); // s now holds the correct data.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in fcgio.cpp

The `fcgi_steambuf` class is defined using `char_type`, but the `int underflow()` method downcasts  its return value to `(unsigned char)`, it should cast to `(char_type)`.

Comment: This does indeed seem to fix the problem, but I don't quite understand why casting it to `unsigned char` before returning causes every other character to disappear

Answer (score 1):

Use `is.read()` not `is >> ...`

Sample from restcgi documentation:

```
clen = strtol(clenstr, &clenstr, 10);
if (*clenstr)
{
    cerr << "can't parse \"CONTENT_LENGTH="
          << FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request->envp)
          << "\"\n";
    clen = STDIN_MAX;
}

// *always* put a cap on the amount of data that will be read
if (clen > STDIN_MAX) clen = STDIN_MAX;

*content = new char[clen];

is.read(*content, clen);
clen = is.gcount();
```